# How do you submit a form with input from Bootstrap 3 radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

With the recent update to twitter Bootstrap, the functionality for submitting a form based on input from radio buttons has been lost. Any idea of how to work around the new update?

EDIT: This is not to submit the form with the radio buttons, but that the values of the radio buttons aren't being added to the post string when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: Submitting a form with radio buttons? That seems like poor UI design. Why not make three buttons?

Comment: use an `onclick` event trigger and submit the form that way.  But I agree with @JasCav, that's very poor UI design.

Comment: Sure you read the doc? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls

Comment: Radio buttons are only sent when they are selected, is this the case?